# Assign value from array as key and merge records of same key

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have array like below in PHP (Codeigniter). I want to group them by using country names. So value of country key will become key of outer array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Buenos Aires
            [country] => Argentina
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => Adelaide
            [country] => Australia
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => Brisbane
            [country] => Australia
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [city] => Fremantle
            [country] => Australia
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [city] => Melbourne
            [country] => Australia
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [city] => Sydney
            [country] => Australia
        )

)
```

I want to convert it into array like below so country will become key with city list as per country name

```
Array
(
    [Argentina] => Array
    (
        [0] => Buenos Aires
    )

    [Australia] => Array
    (
        [0] => Adelaide
        [1] => Brisbane
        [2] => Melbourne
        [3] => Sydney
    )

)
```

Comment: Show some code first.

Comment: @u_mulder.. I tried many things in for loop but was not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
$arr = [//your arr];

$result = []; // will be your output

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
   $result[$v['country']][] = $v['city'];
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Welcome ! If this solution solves your problem, please accept my answer.